# Text with Splashscreen API

Tags: android, android-splashscreen

Is it possible to add a text to the logo in splash screen while using Splash Screen API?
I did not find any property regarding "text" in Theme.SplashScreen.

```
    <style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/black_accent</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/circle_orange</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">200</item>
        <!-- Set the theme of the Activity that directly follows your splash screen. -->
        <!-- Required -->
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.MyApplication</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Currently there is no support for text in the `SplashScreen` api.

Comment: @MohammedAli: What you are seeking is not directly an option. The closest is [to have two splash screens](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen/migrate#best-practices), where you use an animation to change from the system-defined splash screen to your custom one that is designed the way that you seek.

Comment: There is a solution.  I think the answer below could be made to work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such property yet but you can add yours by converting your text to drawable and then placing your logo + text drawable inside
`<item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/circle_orange</item>`, this is not a proper solution but you can consider this as an option.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not allowed in the current Splash API. That is a bit of a headache for some devs including me also.

What I suggest is the only way forward which is to create a custom Splash Screen - The Classical Way :)

Comment: CommonsWare's response is also good - 'The closest is to have two splash screens, where you use an animation to change from the system-defined splash screen to your custom one that is designed the way that you seek'