# Add Text in Splash Screen above android 12

Tags: android, kotlin, android-splashscreen, dynamic-splash-screen

Is it possible to add a text below the logo in splash screen while using Splash Screen API? I did not find any property regarding "text" in Theme.SplashScreen.

I have also tried the following link to solve the problem but that not helped to me. Is anyother
way to achieve this requirement.[expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOI9c.png) [Text with Splashscreen API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73690553/text-with-splashscreen-api)

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for text in the SplashScreen api as of now.

You can achieve what you want by

1. creating a custom splash screen activity as the launcher activity.
2. Set the colors and icons of the SplashScreen api to transparent by editing Theme.SplashScreen.

Result: You will have two splash screens one from SplashScreen api and the custom splash screen, since the former is transparent it will not be reflected in the app.

Comment: But when we upload the App Playstore crawler detect throws error like custom splash screen that is shown in your app after the system splash screen.

Comment: Don't use the word splash for naming the splash activity, use LaucherActivity or something else.